# how to get few records using sql query from one row where date =sys_date and few records from another row where date=prev_date. From a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to get dat from a table based on -
field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4 will be system dates data and field_5,field_6,field_7,field_8 will be previous days data, and date will be system date.

Pls check the below image for better clarification.

[image: Please check the image]

Comment: Can you create two queries (the second will have date + 1 as date)  and join them by date columns?

Comment: What about using `LAG` window function?

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `join`:

```
select t.*, tprev.*   -- select the columns you want so you don't get duplicates
from t join
     t tprev
     on tprev.fid = t.fid and
        tprev.date = dateadd(day, -1, t.date);
```

I'm guessing you want this per `fid`, which is why that condition is included.  If `fid` is irrelevant, just remove that condition from whichever query you use.

Note:  This specifically gets the previous *day* based on the calendar and does not return results when there is no previous day.  If you want the previous day in the table, then one option is `lag()` . . . but I think `apply` is more elegant:

```
select t.*, tprev.*  
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) . . .    -- the columns you want here
      from t tprev
      where tprev.fid = t.fid and
            tprev.date < t.date
      order by tprev.date desc
    ) tprev;
```

Comment: <nag>Why the `fid`'s? Based on the images, they might or might not be relevant but it's impossible to say? Perhaps for OP's benefit to better use the names as in the screenshot. `Table_1` io `t` and `f_id` io `fid`.</nag>

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers . . . Experience.  I'm guessing the OP really wants it per `fid` and it was so obvious that the OP forgot to mention it.